# Theme color switch only once in react using material-ui?

Tags: material-ui

I have this dark/light theme setup.
for some reason it is not switching any idea what is the culprit ? the light state is getting updated on click but only once.. then the theme is not changing.

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-flower-r0och?file=/src/Test.js:0-898)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import EmojiObjectsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/EmojiObjects";

const themeLight = createTheme({
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: "#e4f0e2"
    }
  }
});

const themeDark = createTheme({
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: "#222222"
    },
    text: {
      primary: "#ffffff"
    }
  }
});

export default function SignIn() {
  const [light, setLight] = useState(true);

  console.log(light);
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={light ? themeLight : themeDark}>
      <EmojiObjectsIcon onClick={() => setLight((prev) => !prev)} />
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```